# Why is jQuery .live() not working with my .ajaxForm() invocation here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that looks like the following:

```
jQuery("[name='myform']").live('submit', function() {
    $(this).ajaxForm({
    target: '#someform',
    beforeSerialize: function(form, options) {
      alert("BeforeSerialize happening.");
      jQuery('form[name=myform] input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr("value", "<%= t('labels.please_wait') %>");
          return true;
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return false;
    },

    success: function() {
      jQuery('#form_quotes_highlights_part').fadeIn('slow');
    },

    complete: function() {
      jQuery("#wizard").expose().close();
    }
  });
 });
```

The live() binding seems to work just fine, however the ajaxForm is not working at all. If I do something like:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      /* ajax form stuff here */
 });
```

It appears to work just fine. The only problem with that is, when the response comes back from the server, javascript handlers are not attaching themselves to the DOM properly, hence the use of live(). Either way, beforeSerialize is never invoked with the way I'm currently handling my live() handler, so instead of an ajaxForm, I'm having a full page submit.

What's the best way to clean this up?

Comment: There is some code missing. You have an `else` but no `if`.

Answer (score 1):

I never used the `ajaxForm` plugin, but looking at its [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/), it looks like the call to `ajaxForm` simply *sets up* the form, it doesn't actually *submit* the form.  So when your function that is bound to the form's submit function is called, the form is already being submitted, and thus it is too late to set up the form as an AJAX form via `ajaxForm`.

If I understand correctly, the `myform` form doesn't exist on the page when the page is loaded; instead, it's being inserted into the page by an AJAX call at some point.  The `success` callback of that AJAX call is where you should be calling `ajaxForm` as well in order to prep the form ahead of time for when the user submits it.  e.g.:

```
$.get('/get_my_form', function(data) {
    $('form[name="myform"]').html(data).ajaxForm({
        target: '#someform',
        beforeSerialize: function(form, options) {
            $('form[name=myform] input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr("value", "<%= t('labels.please_wait') %>");
            return false;
        },
        success: function() {
            jQuery('#form_quotes_highlights_part').fadeIn('slow');
        },
        complete: function() {
            jQuery("#wizard").expose().close();
        }
    });
});
```